# Blazor Client No asp.net Hosting, How do I set up web config file for SPA so I don't have to use iis

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I am not using an API or .net Host, I am just trying to use Blazor Client but I need to configure web.config properly. I can't find a single video or site that deals with this. I am hoping it is an easy fix and I by passed the site. Most people working with API and or a server/iis/.host I am not trying to mess with that right now. I am just trying to use blazor and learn web assembly thank you :)

Comment: on linux hosting all you need is to add the wasm mimetype to the haccess file on iis I have no idea

Comment: What is the WASM MIMETYPE THOUGH?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly?view=aspnetcore-6.0#standalone-deployment), there are several ways of hosting the static files (iis, nginx, apache, Github Pages, Azure Storage, etc.)

Comment: Why does it send me to that page in dutch not english?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any sensitive configuration data will be available to the end user as it will be read and used by the blazor app on the client machine.

If you're more used to writing .Net Core MVC apps then write all your configuration data in a JSON file and place it on the server next to the index.html file serving your blazor app.
Try reading it by using the HttpClient class from your blazor app.
This option is probably best for separating development and production versions of the required values.

Another good way would be to create a Configuration class in your blazor app, which could just be a collection of string properties and they would then be easily accessed by your blazor application.
I would use this choice if the configuration doesn't need to change very often.

Comment: I am not using any sensitive information or anything like that that is why I am just trying to figure out how to set it up

Comment: I rephrased my answer @daddycardona , based on your comment.

Answer (score 0):

for the ipage host I literally had to point to the wwwroot folder which had the index.html page in it. I thought I done this before but I guess I have not hopefully that is all I need but it worked. Like I said I am not trying to use an api but maybe in the future I might thanks Stack overflow :)